# Text Property Confusion

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am not sure what is happening, maybe someone can clarify.

The scenario is simple, I have a form that I am submitting to update a DB.

So on `Page_Load`, I set each field to the current value in the current object.

Example:

```
txtFirstName.Text = empInfo.FirstName // FirstName = Jane
txtLastName.Text = empInfo.LastName
// Etc
```

Now at runtime it may be edited by the user, typical textbox stuff.

When I run my button click to update it will always return the assigned `Text` value previously and not the new user-edited value.

Let's say the user edits the field:

`First Name: [    Joe    ]`

If I were to print `txtFirstName.Text`, it is STILL `Jane`

Note: This does not happen if the `Text` property is never set, in that case, it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the code that assigns your `txtFirstName.Text` control/property is running again after post back and overwriting the new value.  Make sure that you initialization code is wrapped in a check for `(!IsPostBack)` to ensure it is only run the first time the page is accessed an not with every post back (update) to the page.

Post your `Page_Load` code or where you do the initialization and we can probably confirm this is the issue.